# Call to undefined function function_exists() if in second argument on OR statement

Tags: php

I have a some code to enable or disable APC for each environment based in some criteria. All works fine, but when I copy and paste some if statements in reverse order I got an unknown PHP error without any logic. I have PHP 5.5.7 and script run in CLI mode.

```
// Works fine
$test = ( function_exists('apc_fetch') || ini_get('apc.enabled') );

// Fail with "Call to undefined function  function_exists()"
$test = ( ini_get('apc.enabled') || function_exists('apc_fetch') );

// Works fine because true do lazy check in OR
$test = ( true || function_exists('apc_fetch') );

// Fail with "Call to undefined function  function_exists()"
$test = ( false || function_exists('apc_fetch') );
```

Somebody can explain that? It's so curious.

The current solution is put the function_exists('apc_fetch') in first position in OR check, but this is not a solution...

**EDIT**: @dev-null-dweller got the trick, the problem was a simply non-unicode char for space between || and function_exists()

Comment: Works as expected for me. Is this *truly* the code you're using? If you just put `<?php $test = ( false || function_exists('apc_fetch') );` alone in a php file and run it, do you still get your strange result? Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Are you sure there is no unicode non-printable character around/inside `function_exists`? like space between it and `||` can be no-breakable space and be treated as part of function name.

Comment: Oooh, interesting point, @dev-null-dweller. Note in the failure messages in the question, there's some extra space between "Call to undefined function" and "function_exists()"; normally there's only a single space character between the error description and the function name...

Comment: Yup, I think you've called it. I just reproduced it with a non-breaking space; the space shows up in the error message, too. @Tecnocat, try deleting all the space before your call to `function_exists()`. (You can replace it by typing a single space.)

Comment: Yes @MattGibson, the problem was a non-printable character around || and function_exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tested this code

```
<?php
$test = ( false || function_exists('apc_fetch') );
var_dump($test);
?>
```

and got this output

```
bool(false)
```

so it's working for me.. somethign strange going on..  can you try this?

```
$test = ( !function_exists('apc_fetch') && ini_get('apc.enabled') );
```

or this?

```
$test = ( false || ( function_exists('apc_fetch') ) );
```

Comment: That's right, removing the non-unicode space char works fine, thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest that in an edit, but it was 4 in the morning and I was like, nah... couldn't be.